# Simple question from a very no experienced programmer

Tags: c#

Simple question: This is a method I created

```
public void move()
{
    double radians = direction * Math.PI / 180;
    //change the x location by the x vector of the speed
    X_Coordinate += (int)(speed * Math.Cos(radians));

    //change the y location by the y vectior of the speed
    Y_Coordinate -= (int)(speed * Math.Sin(radians));
}
```

How do I take a value enter into a text box, use a button called move, to call this method and display the result?

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Do you already have the `TextBox`? The `Button`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Visual studio 2008. I have my form complete and ready

Comment: I wish I could someone could actually show me what I need to type. I'm a visual learner and once I see it, I can take the information and apply it tothe rest of my buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the video tutorial from ASP.Net at http://www.asp.net/general/videos/intro-to-aspnet-controls on an introduction on asp.net controls. It will help you define a button with an event.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio then...

Open the designer, and, from the toolbox, drag a `TextBox` and a `Button` onto the page (along with any other `TextBox` items you need, I'll assume you have them from now on.
Double click the button you just placed on the page. This creates an event handler, code within the scope of this block will execute when the button has been clicked.
Place the following code within the generated event handler code block, changing appropriately (e.g. `TextBox` names (You can change these using the `Property Explorer` within VS)):

```
var direction = 0;
if (int.TryParse(DirectionTextBox.Text, out direction))
{
    //further validate input here, as necessary

    Move(direction);
    XTextBox.Text = X_Coordinate.ToString();
    YTextBox.Text = Y_Coordinate.ToString();
}
else
{
    //handle invalid input, if not already done elsewhere.
}
```

Presumably here `X_Coordinate` and `Y_Coordinate` are accessible variables. So, now, alter your move method to accept a parameter, like so:

```
public void Move(int direction)
{
    double radians = direction * Math.PI / 180;
    //change the x location by the x vector of the speed
    X_Coordinate += (int)(speed * Math.Cos(radians));

    //change the y location by the y vectior of the speed
    Y_Coordinate -= (int)(speed * Math.Sin(radians));
}
```

Note that by this point I have no idea which of the elements of the `Move` method you wish to be variable input, but I'll keep thinking along the lines of this being an idea to can extend to as many elements as you like/need. Also note that there are many other ways to go about this - what I suggest is neat enough (given the information we have) and not too far altered from your initially posted code, hence, hopefully, easier for you to implement; but you could return a composite type from this method, and set visual outputs with the directly returned result to make things more concise.

Comment: How do you out put that to a label?

Answer (score 0):

Hook up the Click event of the button, and in the event handler you can access the entered value by `TextBoxName.Text`. You will probably need to parse the string value using `int.Parse` in order to use it in a calculation.

Your button will look something like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="MoveBtn" runat="server" onclick="Move" Text="Move" />
```

And then in your code behind

```
protected void Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Call your move method here.
   // If it is in the same class, it's just move();
   // Otherwise you need a reference to your class so you can call it.
}
```

Comment: Can I make it to where the user can only enter in a integer?

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer, yes. Have a look at the different types of field validators. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx Also, you can ensure that they entered a number by using the int.TryParse instead.