# How do I code an event that calls a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

OK,

I have 5 methods

Move(), TurnRight(), TurnLeft(), Accelerate(), Decelerate()

I have 5 buttons on my windows form called:

Move, Turn Right, Turn Left, Accelerate, Decelerate

How do take values entered from texboxes and store them, so that when a user clicks one of those buttons it calls the method to perform calculations, and then display the information.

I just don't know how or what to code inside the event that I activated from the form.
Can anyone show me a sample of how they would do it?

Here is my move method

public void move()
        {
            double radians = direction * Math.PI / 180;

```
        //change the x location by the x vector of the speed
        X_Coordinate += (int)(speed * Math.Cos(radians));

        //change the y location by the y vectior of the speed
        Y_Coordinate -= (int)(speed * Math.Sin(radians));


    }
```

I created a button on my form and named it btnMove

What should I code inside the event for my move button to call the move method and the display that for an outcome?

Comment: This is obviously homework so you should show what you've accomplished so far.

Comment: You might want to describe a little more about what you have tried so far and what you are having trouble with, otherwise we don't know where to begin.

Comment: Stop creating duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763503/simple-question-from-a-very-no-experienced-programmer , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763962/beginner-programmer-needs-help-closed , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764199/updated-question-from-a-beginner-closed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to calculate the info in two text boxes, and show the result in the third, you cold do this.

```
private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    var y = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    textBox3.Text = (x + y).ToString();
}
```

say you shold pass the value over to the move method, you cold do this
change the `textBox3.Text = (x + y).ToString();` with `move(x + y);` if the move takes in an int like this

```
public void move(int vaule)
{
   //do stuff with value
}
```

Comment: Could I display the info into a label?

Comment: yes you just change the textBox3.Text out with label1.Text.. like this label1.Text = x + y.ToString();

Comment: @Darkmage, same thing for 4 textboxes

Comment: ok, i did that but when I run my program there is no return to the label. So i'm guessing its not calling the move method. What should I have in my move method that lets it no the move btn will call?

Comment: post your code for both the button klick event and the move() in an update at top, it wold be easyer for us understand what error you are typing.

Answer (score 1):

For each buttons click event (Double click on button in designer to open code for click event)
call your respective method.

However its not clear if your Move()...etc methods take Values.

You can try this

```
public void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Move();
}

public void Move()
{        
     string thetext = Convert.ToInt32(this.textbox1.Text);
     //Perform Calculations
}
```

similarly for other buttons

Answer (score 0):

I would store the initial values of the textboxes outside the method in the initiation of the class. Then in the button click event update the values that have changed. E.g.

int val1 = parseInt(textbox1.text);

int val2 = parseInt(textbox2.text);

private void Move()

{

```
 val2 = parseInt(textbox2.text);
```

}